# Exception appending DataFrame chunk with string values to large HDF5 file using pandas

Tags: pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

An exception happens while appending `pandas.DataFrame()` with string values (numerical values are OK) to HDF5 storage after filesize is greater than approximately 47 GiB. Neither minimal size of string, number of records, number of columns is not important. Filesize is important.

The bottom of the exception trace:

```
  File "..\..\hdf5-1.8.14\src\H5FDsec2.c", line 822, in H5FD_sec2_write
file write failed: time = Tue Aug 18 18:26:17 2015
, filename = 'large_file.h5', file descriptor = 4, errno = 22, error message = 'Invalid argument', buf = 0000000066A40018, total write size = 262095, bytes this sub-write = 262095, bytes actually written = 18446744073709551615, offset = 47615949533
```

the code to reproduce:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

for i in range(200):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.char.mod('random string object (%f)', np.random.rand(5000000,3)), columns=('A','B','C'))
    print('writing chunk №', i, '...', end='', flush=True)
    with pd.HDFStore('large_file.h5') as hdf:
        # Construct unique index
        try:
            nrows = hdf.get_storer('df').nrows
        except:
            nrows = 0
        df.index = pd.Series(df.index) + nrows    

        # Append the dataframe to the storage. Exception hppens here
        hdf.append('df', df, format='table')
    print('done')
```

Environment:
Windows7 x64 machine, python 3.4.3, pandas 0.16.2, pytables 3.2.0, HDF5 1.8.14.

The question is how to fix the problem if it is located in python code above or how to avoid it if related to HDF5. Thanks.

Comment: try with Pytables 3.2.1 release quite recently

Comment: PyTables 3.2.1 didn't solve the problem

Comment: you might try the hdfgroup guys. That looks like an exception from HDF5 itself.

Comment: I'll provide feedback here if I get an answer from hdfgroup. Suppose, problem can also be in DataFrame layout (DataFrame references its string objects which are actually stored somewhere apart) and the way PyTables serializes it in HDF5.

Comment: hdfgroup's support was very responsive. It looks like my own configuration problem. Same code on another PC runs well.